# how to integrate two table column in HQL @Query

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, union, hql

We can not use union because it's not supported in HQL.
what is the alternative way to combine two different table without use of union and join in HQL?
We can not use "or" to combine tables because there is no similar table or column.
We can also make two different query and then combine in a list but that is not good for us so rather then this if any solutions will work , please suggest

Sql query which we want to achieve in HQL.

```
select m.* from (select a.* from a1 a where a.id=1 union select b.* from b1 b where b.id =1) m order by m.id desc
```

Is it possible?
Answer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do the tables have the same data structure? If yes you could use the INSERT INTO...SELECT statement, since it is supported in HQL.

In SQL it would look like:

```
  insert into a select b.* from b where b.id =1
```

For the INSERT INTO...SELECT statement in HQL take a look here:

https://mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-query-examples-hql/

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way, write a DAO method like this:

```
List<MyObject> result = query1.getResult();
result.addAll(query2.getResult());
```

So if you want to sort or page it is not a good solution, but fast.

If you want sort or page on this query I would create a view.
This view you can map as entity.

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXIST myview as
SELECT * FROM a
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM b;
```

And make HQL on view based entity.